# How to repair wmic

Tags: windows-10, wmic

I'm getting `Invalid XML content` error when I call any `wmic os` operation. e.g.

```
> wmic os get Caption
Invalid XML content.
```

I've tried

```
winmgmt /resetrepository
```

But it had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `sfc /scannow` reported corrupted files. The `scf` log file located at `%WINDIR%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log` mentioned that `basebrd.dll.mui` is corrupt. I've copied `basebrd.dll.mui` from another Windows 10 machine and it fixed the problem.